# How to center a cut on a circle based upon an inner shape with Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustration

I have a circle and a minus sign in it I want to cut the circle right of the sign. What are the ways to cut the same amount above and below the sign(I want the cut part to be centered):

[image]

Comment: Draw a box thats aligned to your center then cut at intersections or use shapebuilder. Or cut one side delete the side then mirror the upper side. Or draw a vertical line and cut/pathfind that. Or take your centerline shift  copydrag to right make thicker expand. Or use a guideline and use nuneric input copies with rotate tool. Or dicide the segments and delete spans...

Comment: @joojaa did you *leave* any other method? 

Comment: As per joojaa's comment, there are infinite ways to do it... It's kind of a broad question as it is, you're requesting a list of solutions. What have you tried and what failed?

Comment: @Luciano originally he mentioned the word "scissors" so I feel he tried using scissors.

Answer (score 0):

If the circle is a stroke, you can create guides with the help of a centered rectangle and then use scissors tool to cut the portion:

[image]

If it's not a stroke, use multiple points for scissors and then remove the unwanted part using Direct Selection Tool. Then join the ends using <kbd>Cntl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and then round the corners.

[image]

Comment: You dont need the guides you know. you can snap to the square.

Comment: @joojaa yeah I just used so it doesn't mess with it. I could lock the square also though.